# Setting a workbook variable to a shared workbook

Tags: vba, shared

I am trying to work with multiple workbooks, one of them being a shared workbook. 
As far as my testing has gone, it looks like I cannot set a workbook/worksheet variable to that of the shared workboook.

Is there a way that I haven't figured out, or is this impossible without first unsharing?

Below are the methods I have tested (while having the shared workbook as the active workbook):

```
Sub TestAssign()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range

    With Workbooks("testSHARE.xlsb")
        Set ws = .Sheets(1)
    End With

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set r = Range("A1:P5")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify shared workbook if the shared workbook is set for corraboration.

Setup procedure is explained at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-HP010096833.aspx .

Comment: This just tells me how to set a workbook as shared/unshared. It also mentions nothing to do with VBA!

Comment: Shared workbook is not modifiable. This is first step to solve your  problem. You never be able to solve without this information.

Comment: So are you saying that this is impossible without first unsharing? (this was part of my original question)